# Can I send messages from a client-side application to a server-side application using RDP virtual channels?

Tags: c#, rdp, virtual-channel

One of our integration partners is migrating their product to Terminal Services. While their product will exist within a Terminal Services session they will not allow third-parties to run their applications within the same session.

Our integration requires that our application send messages to the partner product using built-in APIs. These APIs have not been updated to allow communication across the RDP session. We want to be able to send these messages via a proxy in the form of a virtual channel. These messages would be received by the RDP session, forwarded on to the partner application, and any responses returned to our application via the channel.

However, all articles I've found on the web surround the process of sending messages *from* the server to the client. Is the reverse possible?